# Duplicate Fields after Join with Python script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I created a Python script to join multible tables to a feature class from a GDB. Some parameters (TabelaE2 and TabelaE3) are optional, so I put some conditions for a blank field. The script join perfectly the fields, but for some reason the columns are has been duplicate.

No errors appears after the join.

```
import arcpy

TabelaP1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
TabelaE1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
TabelaE2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
TabelaE3 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
CampoChave1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
CampoSaida = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)

arcpy.AddMessage('Tabelas Selecionadas...Efetuando Joins')

if TabelaE2 == "":

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(TabelaP1, "brasilmunlyrt2")
    arcpy.JoinField_management(TabelaP1, CampoChave1, TabelaE1, CampoSaida, "")
    arcpy.JoinField_management(TabelaP1, CampoChave1, TabelaE3, CampoSaida, "")

elif TabelaE3 == "":

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(TabelaP1, "brasilmunlyrt2")
    arcpy.JoinField_management(TabelaP1, CampoChave1, TabelaE1, CampoSaida, "")
    arcpy.JoinField_management(TabelaP1, CampoChave1, TabelaE2, CampoSaida, "")

else:

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(TabelaP1, "brasilmunlyrt2")
    arcpy.JoinField_management(TabelaP1, CampoChave1, TabelaE1, CampoSaida, "")
    arcpy.JoinField_management(TabelaP1, CampoChave1, TabelaE2, CampoSaida, "")
    arcpy.JoinField_management(TabelaP1, CampoChave1, TabelaE3, CampoSaida, "")

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("brasilmunlyrt2", "F:\AgroBD.gdb\BrasilMunJ")
arcpy.AddMessage('Concluido')
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your results.

Comment: ArcGIS does not support duplicate field names, but there might be duplicate aliases.

Comment: Do the tables have fields in common other than the join field? If so you might want to delete these in your code

Comment: I'd check to see that only one condition is being called within your if statements. Duplication might occur if E2 and E3 tables are both empty.

Comment: @preardon I have moved your comments from the answer section to the comment section. Please only use the answer area for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved! Many thanks for the comments and suggestions. Here is the code.

```
import arcpy

TabelaP1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
TabelaE1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
TabelaE2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
TabelaE3 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
CampoChave1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
CampoSaida = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)

arcpy.AddMessage('Tabelas Selecionadas...Efetuando Joins')

if TabelaE2 == "" and TabelaE3 == "":

    arcpy.AddMessage("Tabelas 2 e 3 ausentes. Executando Join com "         
+TabelaE1+'.')
    arcpy.JoinField_management(TabelaP1, CampoChave1, TabelaE1, CampoSaida, "")

elif TabelaE2 == "":

    arcpy.AddMessage("Tabelas 2 ausente. Executando Join com "+TabelaE1+" e"+TabelaE3)
arcpy.JoinField_management(TabelaP1, CampoChave1, TabelaE1, CampoSaida, "")
arcpy.JoinField_management(TabelaP1, CampoChave1, TabelaE3, CampoSaida, "")

elif TabelaE3 == "":

    arcpy.JoinField_management(TabelaP1, CampoChave1, TabelaE1, CampoSaida, "")
    arcpy.JoinField_management(TabelaP1, CampoChave1, TabelaE2, CampoSaida, "")

arcpy.AddMessage('Concluido')
```